# Populating complex Map and accessing its values

Tags: java, dictionary, comparator

Problem 1: I want to add "specific" sorted values of the following "Class Dog"  into the "Map" used in the Class "Ser". But i do not know how to achieve this,

Problem 2: How to Accessing the populated value of the map if it successfully populated

The following is my desperate Attempt.

```
 class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog>{

   private double Price;
 private String Operator;
  Dog(){
   }

  Dog( double p, String o){

   Price= p;
   Operator=o;
  }

  public double getPrice(){
  return Price;
  }
    public String getOperator(){
      return Operator;
   }


  // Overriding the compareTo method
  public int compareTo(Dog d){

   double data= Price - d.Price; 
   if ( data > 0.00001)return 1;
   if (data < 0.00001) return -1;
   return 0;
 }


   // Overriding the compare method to sort the age 
  public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1){

  double data= d.Price - d1.Price; 

   if ( data > 0.00001)return 1;
   if (data < 0.00001) return -1;
   return 0;

      }

}

 public class Ser {                          
   /**                                     
    * @param args
   */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
// Takes a list o Dog objects
ArrayList <Dog> list1 = new ArrayList<Dog>();

Map <Integer, ArrayList<Dog> > map= new HashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Dog> > ();

  list1.add(new Dog(0.99 , "A"));
  list1.add(new Dog(0.91 , "C"));
  list1.add(new Dog(0.92 , "A"));
  list1.add(new Dog(0.97 , "B"));
  list1.add(new Dog( 0.93 , "C"));
  list1.add(new Dog(0.97 , "B"));
  list1.add(new Dog(0.92, "A"));
  list1.add(new Dog(0.97, "C"));
  list1.add(new Dog(0.92, "A"));
  // Sorts the array list using comparator

  Collections.sort(list1, new Dog());

  for(Dog a: list1)//printing the sorted list of ages
      System.out.println( a.getOperator()+"  : "+ a.getPrice());

  map.put(92,  list1);
  map.put(445, list1);
  map.put(966, list1);

 // Collections.sort(list1, new Dog());

 for (ArrayList<Dog> key: map.values() )     
         System.out.println(key);
         }

   }
```

OutPut: C  : 0.91, A  : 0.92, A  : 0.92, A  : 0.92, C  : 0.93, C  : 0.97, B  : 0.97, 
B  : 0.97,A  : 0.99

Output of Map Values: 
[Dog@a981ca, Dog@8814e9, Dog@1503a3, Dog@1a1c887, Dog@743399, Dog@e7b241, Dog@167d940, Dog@e83912, Dog@1fae3c6]
[Dog@a981ca, Dog@8814e9, Dog@1503a3, Dog@1a1c887, Dog@743399, Dog@e7b241, Dog@167d940, Dog@e83912, Dog@1fae3c6]
[Dog@a981ca, Dog@8814e9, Dog@1503a3, Dog@1a1c887, Dog@743399, Dog@e7b241, Dog@167d940, Dog@e83912, Dog@1fae3c6]

Comment: Implement a `toString` method on your Dog class.

Comment: I am sorry did not get you , how it solve my problem. any code example?

Comment: override the toString() from the object class to show meaningful value instead of the hashcode

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing the `Object.toString` representation of `Dog`, you need to override that method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Dog [Price=" + Price + ", Operator=" + Operator + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

You've created a `Map` object that creates an Integer Key and maps it to a *list of* Dogs. If you are wishing to map Integers to Dogs you need to start off with this:

```
Map <Integer, Dog> map= new HashMap <Integer, Dog> ();
```

Now, assuming your sort is working (I haven't looked into it, I'll let you debug to prove if it is or not) you need to use the `.get(int)` method of the `List` collection to fetch the dog *from* the list you wish to put into the map.

What you are doing right now is mapping different integers to the same list 3 times.

```
map.put(92, list1.get(0));
```

The 0 refers to the first Dog object in the `list1` List, pick whatever you need in place of 0.

Now, for **Problem 2** where you need to print them you'll have to roll a `toString()` function like Reimeus said or do it manually.

```
for (Dog d : map.values()) {
  System.out.println("Dog " + d.getPrice() + " " + d.getOperator());
}
```

Again, what you were doing previously was fetching the `List` object you had mapped to integers in the map. If you were to keep that format you'd have to then iterate over each value in the List:

```
for (List<Dog> ld : map.values()) {
  for (Dog d : ld) {
    System.out.println(...);
  }
}
```

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Thank you for improvision. It is useful answer.